# Как писать приложения для андроид на c++?

Tags: android, c++, qt, visual-studio, qtcreator

Можно ли вообще написать код на `c++` а потом скомпилировать в `.apk`. Как это можно сделать в `Visual Studio` или `Qt`?

Comment: Гуглить по ключевому слову NDK.

Comment: Qt использует NDK